# How do I properly pass function props on another component with React.Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am introducing my self in es6+, I have a hard time trying to pass a function props to another component.

This is my code:

```
 class ProductList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onVote = this.handleProductUpVote.bind(this);
    }
    handleProductUpVote(productId) {
        console.log(productId +" was upvoted.")
    }
    render() {
        const products = Data.map((product) => {
            return (
                <Product 
                    key={'product-'+product.id}
                    id={product.id}
                    title={product.title}
                    description={product.description}
                    url={product.url}
                    votes={product.votes}
                    submitter_avatar_url={product.submitter_avatar_url}
                    product_image_url={product.product_image_url}
                    onVote={this.handleProductUpVote}
                />

            );
        });

        return (
            <div className="ui items">
                {products}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to pass the function onVote in this component(Product)

```
class Product extends React.Component {
    handleUpVote() {
        this.props.onVote(this.props.id).bind(this) /* the error is here, I am trying
 to pass the id props, and invoke the onVote prop here */
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="item">
                <div className="image">
                    <img src={this.props.product_image_url} />
                </div>
                <div className="middle aligned content">
                    <div className="description">
                        <a onClick={this.handleUpVote}>
                            <i className="large caret up icon"/>
                        </a>
                        {this.props.votes}
                    </div>
                    <div className="description">
                        <a href={this.props.url}>
                        {this.props.title}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="extra">
                        <span> Submitted by: </span>
                        <img 
                            className="ui avatar image"
                            src={this.props.submitter_avatar_url}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have no problem with other props here. I am trying to invoke the function on handleUpVote, I used bind with it, but I can't make it work. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use bounded `handleProductUpVote` method when you pass it to Product component.

As you can see in constructor, you already bound it and assigned to `this.onVote` property.

There are 2 solutions:

1. You should use `onVote={this.onVote}` in render method.
2. Change the name of property `onVote` in constructor to `this.handleProductUpVote`. And you end up with `this.handleProductUpVote = this.handleProductUpVote.bind(this)` and leave assignment in render method (i.e. `onVote={this.handleProductUpVote}`)

More info at http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/

Update:

And update your Product class:

```
class Product extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleUpVote = this.handleUpVote.bind(this);
    }
    handleUpVote() {
        this.props.onVote(this.props.id)
    }
    // the render method
}
```

Comment: so this is what i did,on 
      constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.onVote = this.handleProductUpVote.bind(this);
 } and on Product component onVote={this.onVote}, invoked on Product component like this,
        handleUpVote() {
  this.props.onVote(this.props.id);
 }, i still have "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null",  from your answer, it's what I understand. can you please elaborate me how to do it? I'd really appreciate

Comment: I've updated the answer with fixed Product component. You were binding handleUpVote in the wrong way, it should be done in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bind in handleUpVote() in your Product component and just invoke it like `this.props.onVote(this.props.id);`

Comment: I still have the error in it. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null"

Comment: Oh, like Przemyslaw said, to extend my answer, in your ProductList component render() pass it as a prop like onVote={this.onVote} instead of onVote={this.handleProductUpVote}

Comment: so this is what i did,on constructor(props) { super(props); this.onVote = this.handleProductUpVote.bind(this); } and on Product component onVote={this.onVote}, invoked on Product component like this, handleUpVote() { this.props.onVote(this.props.id); }, i still have "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null", from your answer, it's what I understand. can you please elaborate me how to do it? I'd really appreciate